# What is the stack limit when MATLAB calls function in DLL

Tags: c, matlab, dll, stack-overflow

I am trying to figure out, what is the stack size limitation, when MATLAB calls function in DLL.
Is there a way to configure the limit?

I am using `loadlibrary`, and `calllib` functions to call function implemented in C (in Dynamic-link library).

I created a test to figure out the stack limit.

I am using MATLAB 2016a (64 bits), and Visual Studio 2010 for building the DLL.

Here is my MATLAB source code:

```matlab
loadlibrary('MyDll','MyDll.h')

size_in_bytes = 1000000;

res = calllib('MyDll', 'Test', size_in_bytes);

if (res == -1)
    disp(['Stack Overflow... (size = ', num2str(size_in_bytes), ')']);
else
    disp(['Successful stack allocation... (size = ', num2str(size_in_bytes), ')']);
end

unloadlibrary MyDll
```

Here is my C source code:

**MyDll.h**

```
// MyDll.h : DLL interface.

#ifndef MY_DLL_H
#define MY_DLL_H

#ifdef MY_DLL_EXPORTS
    #define MY_DLL_API   __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define MY_DLL_API   __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern MY_DLL_API int Test(int size);

#endif
```

**MyDll.c**

```
// MyDll.c

#include "MyDll.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>


//Allocate <size> bytes in stack using _alloca(size).
//Return 0 if OK.
//Return (-1) in case of stack overflow.
int Test(int size)
{
    //Not allocated on the stack...
    static wchar_t errorMsg[100];
    static wchar_t okMsg[100];

    int errcode = 0;
    void *pData = NULL;

    //Prepare messages from advance.
    swprintf_s(errorMsg, 100, L"Stack Overflow (size = %d)", size);
    swprintf_s(okMsg, 100, L"Successful stack allocation (size = %d)", size);

    __try 
    {
        pData = _alloca(size);
    }
    // If an exception occurred with the _alloca function
    __except (GetExceptionCode() == STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, errorMsg, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

        // If the stack overflows, use this function to restore.
        errcode = _resetstkoflw();
        if (errcode)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Could not reset the stack!"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            _exit(1);
        }

        pData = NULL;
    };

    if (pData != NULL)
    {
        //Fill allocated buffer with zeros
        memset(pData, 0, size);

        MessageBox(NULL, okMsg, TEXT("OK"), MB_OK);

        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The `__try` and `__except` block is taken from Microsoft example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx

DLL Compiler flags:
`/Zi /nologo /W4 /WX- /Od /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_USRDLL" /D "MY_DLL_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MTd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"x64\Debug\MyDll.pch" /Fa"x64\Debug\" /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fd"x64\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /errorReport:queue`

DLL Linker flags:
`/OUT:"x64\Debug\MyDll.dll" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /DLL "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\MyDll.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"c:\Tmp\MyDll\x64\Debug\MyDll.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /PGD:"c:\Tmp\MyDll\x64\Debug\MyDll.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X64 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE`

---

I executed the MATLAB code using different values of `size_in_bytes`:
`size_in_bytes = 1000000`: Pass!
`size_in_bytes = 10000000`: Pass!
`size_in_bytes = 50000000`: Pass!
`size_in_bytes = 60000000`: Pass!
`size_in_bytes = 70000000`: Stack Overflow!

Looks like the limit in my system is about 64MByte (but I don't know if this number is true for all systems).

---

I tried to modify stack size of `Matlab.exe` using [editbin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd3shwhf.aspx) tool.
I tried the following command (for example):
`editbin /STACK:250000000 "c:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\matlab.exe"`.

> This option sets the size of the stack in bytes and takes arguments in decimal or C-language notation. The /STACK option applies only to an executable file.

It seems to have no affect...

Comment: size of the stack is set at execute time so you need to check the size stack allocate by your os. By the way, you give me a heart attack with `__try` in C.

Comment: So how can I set the size in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that on windows the size of the stack is set at compile time. So you can use option [/F](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx) or the binary [EDITBIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd3shwhf.aspx).

For example, you could to edit the following file:

```sh
EDITBIN /STACK:134217728 "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe"
```

This would set the stack size to 128 MB (128 x 1024 x 1024 Bytes = 134217728 Bytes).

Note: be aware that editing the `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\matlab.exe` will have no effect.

Comment: Do you mean using `editbin` to change `Matlab.exe`? Like this: `editbin /stack:250000000 "c:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\matlab.exe"`. It seems to have no affect...

Comment: Your answer seems to be wrong. Can you please delete it?

Comment: @Wollmich `8_000_000 B / 1024 / 1024 => 7.62 MB`, I don't follow you with 128 MB.

Comment: @Stargateur Sorry my mistake. `DUMPBIN /header` returns the stack size in HEX. So I thought `EDITBIN` requires that it's specified in HEX as well.