# What is the stack size of MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, windows-10, 64-bit, stack-size

What is the default stack size of MATLAB R2018a (64-bit)?

It seems that the stack-size is larger than an 64-bit C# program.

**Why I'm asking that**

I'm asking this question because I'm calling Intel MKLs [LAPACKE_dtrtri](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-trtri) which is heavily recursive.

I'm using that function inside .NET application and I'm getting a stack overflow error when calling it from C#, see [What is the stack size of a BackgroundWorker DoWork Thread? Is there way to change it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457637/what-is-the-stack-size-of-a-backgroundworker-dowork-thread-is-there-way-to-chan)

On the other side if I call my .NET application from MATLAB I'm not getting a stack overflow error. That's the reason I wanted to know what the stack size of MATLAB.

Comment: It's 42. Jokes aside: Can you please further elaborate on your question? At least to me, it's not clear, what you exactly want to know.

Comment: Is it possible that this question get's reopened so that I can answer my own question. By the way the stack size of MATLAB seems to be 64 MB and I would like to explain in my answer.

Comment: I asked the following question: [What is the stack limit when MATLAB calls function in DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101043/what-is-the-stack-limit-when-matlab-calls-function-in-dll). I thought stack size is 64MByte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference) command I can take look at the header of the `MATLAB.exe`.

```
dumpbin /headers "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe"
```

This returns

```
Dump of file C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe

PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
...

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
...
         4000000 size of stack reserve
            1000 size of stack commit
          100000 size of heap reserve
            1000 size of heap commit
```

The `size of stack reserve` is the stack size in hex.

So the stack size of MATLAB is 67108864 Bytes which is 64 Mega Bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits` function from `kernel32.dll` I can get the stack size of MATLAB.

I've created the following helper method in an .NET assembly called `IntelMKL.dll`:

```
static class _kernel
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern void GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(out uint lowLimit, out uint highLimit);
}
```

and

```
public static class MKL
{
    public static uint GetStackSize()
    {
        uint low, high;
        _kernel.GetCurrentThreadStackLimits(out low, out high);
        return high - low;
    }
}
```

I can call the `GetStackSize` from MATLAB using the following code:

```
NET.addAssembly('IntelMKL.dll')
IntelMKL.MKL.GetStackSize() % this return 67108864 Bytes which is 64 Mega Bytes
```

**The stack size of MATLAB is 64 MB.**

> It seems that the stack-size is larger than an 64-bit C# program.

The default C# stack size is 1 MB (32-bit) and 4 MB (64-bit), see [What is the stack size of a BackgroundWorker DoWork Thread? Is there way to change it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457637/what-is-the-stack-size-of-a-backgroundworker-dowork-thread-is-there-way-to-chan)

Comment: @Adriaan The default C# stack size is 1 MB (32-bit) and 4 MB (64-bit).

Comment: Just as side information. The stack size of Python 3.6.6 (64-bit) using PYTHONNET is 1984 kB.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not have a direct answer to your question, MATLAB's recursion limit can be obtained by `get(0,'RecursionLimit')` or set by `set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)`.

I believe than other than that, MATLAB will keep storing variables until your RAM runs out, but not 100% sure.

Comment: I guess this `RecursionLimit` is only used for MATLAB functions (m-files) but I've I call a .NET method from MATLAB the stack size is relevant.

Comment: @Wollmich I suspect the *question* is harder than "what is the stack size of MATLAB". Possibly "What is the stack size that MATLAB gives .NET applications when called from within"

Comment: If MATLAB is not creating a new thread for .NET it's the same stack size as MATLAB has. Or not?

Comment: @Wollmich are you doing it through the mex interface? I *think* that matlab creates a locking new thread when it calls it, but I am not sure.

Comment: I'm doing it over the .NET interface, see https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started.html